# Is it possible to log all code run in a jupyter notebook running off emr

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am using jupyter notebook to debug production code and it is running on emr. is there a way i can enable logging of what I am doing from notebook to emr logs so there will be a record.